# How can I run TC ERlectronic TonePrint editor on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation

I need to run TonePrint editor on Ubuntu.
Sadly, this software is only aviable for both mac and windows.
I dont know how to proceed...

Comment: Note: It's now also available for Android and iPhone/iPad. You can "beam" toneprints through your guitar by holding the phone's speaker next to a live guitar pickup. But to live-edit toneprints, apparently you'll need an OTG USB adapter for your phone to connect the mini-USB cable from the pedal to your phone.

Answer (score 1):

You cant run it directly on Ubuntu if the package was built for Windows.

However, you can still run windows application using wine. Here`s [Wine for Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine) that might help you to start with.

1. Install WINE
2. Copy program installer to your Ubuntu box
3. Run the installer using WINE

Comment: Maybe the TonePrint Windows app used to have an installer, but trying for the first time today (TonePrint App Windows (32-bit) 4.5.8) with your instructions, it just works, and couldn't be simpler- I just unzipped the executable and typed "wine TonePrint_32bit_4.5.8_605fa8d.exe" from the command line in the executable's directory. It automatically found my pedal via USB and allowed me to make changes live.
Here's what the wine guys have to say about it:
https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=40817

Answer (score 1):

Even if you get it running with wine, that is not trivial, you will need to recompile wine from sources with some patches in order to use USB connection to the pedal, so my advice is: forget it and run it on a virtual machine or a Windows box.

Comment: Maybe in 2016 this was true, but trying today for the first time, it runs easily under wine, no error messages, automatically found and identified my pedal via usb. Totally transparent.